# How can I exclude RSpec tests matching a specific tag?

Tags: ruby, rspec

When running my RSpec tests from the command line, how can I exclude tests matching a specific tag?

Answer (score 25):

Use `~@` with the name of the tag, like this:

```
rspec spec --tag ~@slow
```

See the docs: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/command-line/tag-option

#### Update

I'm now running my tests on Spork, and it seems as though it ignores this directive. Not sure why.

Comment: Took a bit of Googling to find this, so I just wanted to make it easier for the next person. (Or for me, next week when I forget.)

Comment: It's only Googling that's hard. Reading the documentation is much easier: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/command-line/tag-option  :-P

Comment: Unfortunately, it's too easy to find the RSpec 1 docs, and not easy enough to find the RSpec 2 docs...

Comment: For completeness, the `@` is optional. According to the docs, it's for compatibility with `cucumber` syntax and will be ignored.

Answer (score 7):

I had similar requirements however I wanted the tagged test excluded by default and then only ran when I specific it so I don't have to remember to include the tag each time.

To achieve this I added the following line to my spec helper:

```
config.filter_run_excluding :slow => true
```

Now when I run `rspec .`, it will run everything except tests tagged with `slow`. Alternatively if I want to run the slow tests I can use `rspec . --tag slow`.