# How to configure spec_helper file to get only tags that are associated with before(:context) in Rspec?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have a sample_spec.rb

```
context 'test case', :tag => true do
end
```

In my spec_helper.rb I wanted to skip tests based upon tag present in context Im unable to get context metadata

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:context) do |example|
    // code to filter based upon tags
  end
end
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I exclude RSpec tests matching a specific tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8124762/how-can-i-exclude-rspec-tests-matching-a-specific-tag)

Comment: The question was about `before` hooks using together with tags, the answer suggested is about excluding specs from being run. Those are related only because both mechanisms are supposed to use tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match it this way

```
config.before(:context, tag: true)
```

this should trigger the hook only if the tag was `true`.

you can also access it in `example.metadata`:

```
config.before(:context) do |example| 
  if example.metadata[:tag]
    do_sth
  else
    do_sth_else
  end
end
```

Read more on this in Hooks/filters here: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-10/docs/hooks/filters

and metadata sections here:
https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-10/docs/metadata/user-defined-metadata